# extJS (download tutorial) & Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[extJS tab panel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grouptabs/grouptabs.html) <- here is link which is perfect suits me in my project.
How i can it download to my PC? All code I mean?

Answer (score 0):

That tab panel is part of the ExtJS suite of components which is produced by a company called [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/). It requires a fair amount of set up (which you can check out if you do a 'view source' on the page itself, and look at the JavaScript files included). It's not a pre-formatted page layout that you can just download and use exactly as is. ExtJS feels much like 'Swing' (if you have a Java background) to use. You put together layouts, panels, windows, viewports, etc, to design a whole interface.

Directly from the page, there are three JS files that set up the whole paneling:

```
<!-- page specific --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../shared/examples.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../portal/sample-grid.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="grouptabs.js"></script>
```

Outside of that, you need some specific style sheets to make the look that they have there happen:

```
<!-- overrides to base library --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ux/css/Portal.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ux/css/GroupTab.css" />
```

Those files are above and beyond the base library being included.

If you are interested in learning ExtJS, I would follow Sencha's [learning path](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Learn_About_the_Ext_JavaScript_Library) that is presented on their website. There is a pretty excellent community behind that as well.

Sorry it's not an easy answer!